# Visual Studio performance optimization in branching

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, c#-4.0, optimization, compiler-optimization

Consider the following

```
while(true)
{
    if(x>5)
     // Run function A
    else
     // Run function B
}
```

if x is always less than 5, does visual studio compiler do any optimization? i.e. like never checks if x is larger than 5 and always run function B

Comment: it's the compiler that does optimizations, not visual studio.

Comment: I meant to say VS compiler; does it really do so ? is there a way to confirm that ?

Comment: Yes - check the disassembly. Also optimizing this will depend on the type of variable `x` is: a const will probably result in the check getting optimized away, but if `x` is a complex type overriding `operator>` it probably won't. And remember optimizations depend on compiler flags, which for debug are turned off, so you get either no or minimum optimizations.

Comment: how can I check the disassembly ?

Comment: Additionally the CPU does [branch prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) too. It is able to "remember" which part of the if-statement has been executed more often. It will then optimize the code execution accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether or not the compiler "knows" that `x` will always be less than `5`.

Yes, nearly all modern compilers are capable of removing the branch. But the compiler needs to be able to *prove* that the branch will always go one direction.

---

Here's an example that **can** be optimized:

```
int x = 1;

if (x > 5)
    printf("Hello\n");
else
    printf("World\n");
```

The disassembly is:

```
    sub rsp, 40                 ; 00000028H
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:??_C@_06DKJADKFF@World?6?$AA@
    call    QWORD PTR __imp_printf
```

`x = 1` is provably less than `5`. So the compiler is able to remove the branch.

---

But in this example, even if you always input less than 5, the compiler doesn't know that. It must assume any input.

```
int x;
cin >> x;

if (x > 5)
    printf("Hello\n");
else
    printf("World\n");
```

The disassembly is:

```
    cmp DWORD PTR x$[rsp], 5
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:??_C@_06NJBIDDBG@Hello?6?$AA@
    jg  SHORT $LN5@main
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:??_C@_06DKJADKFF@World?6?$AA@
$LN5@main:
    call    QWORD PTR __imp_printf
```

The branch stays. But note that it actually hoisted the function call out of the branch. So it really optimized the code down to something like this:

```
const char *str = "Hello\n";

if (!(x > 5))
    str = "World\n";

printf(str);
```

Comment: Thanks ... what if i am reading a value from the gui or command line, is there a way to prove to the compiler that the value read from the gui or command line will never change till the process is over ?

Comment: I misread your comment. So here's an update: Unfortunately, no you won't be able to avoid the branch without code-duplication. But in any case, the branch will consistently go the same way so it's almost free due to [branch-prediction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902).